# Conversion of object List to Generic List

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List of object came to me by serialization. 
But I know following:

1. The list is not Empty
2. All types of the list have the same type. I can know this type only dynamically. For example:

   `list[0].GetType()`

How to convert all list to Generic List using above mentioned conditions ?

P.S. I deserialize an array of objects came to me in JSON

```
    {
   "Message": [
      {
         "__type": "GameResponse:#Bridge3.Server",
         "GameId": 1,
         "GameName": "Game1                                  ",
         "PlayerId": 1
      },
      {
         "__type": "GameResponse:#Bridge3.Server",
         "GameId": 2,
         "GameName": "Game2                                  ",
         "PlayerId": 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can't. Change the serialization code to return the proper strongly typed data.

Comment: You can make a generic list by reflection. But what is your usage about? What do you want to do with generated generic list? Explain more please.

Comment: @javad_amiry if the type were know at compile time, you can just `list.OfType<TheType>()`. However, the OP's apparent situation is that the type is unknown at compile time

Comment: Yes, and the reflection (and/or emit) helps us to make generic objects at runtime.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry which makes no sense whatsoever, since you're already dealing with a list of unkown objects, you better treat them as `dynamic` in that case. No need for reflection, unless you want to convert the data to some sort of `Dictionary<string,object>` such as a DataTable or the like.

Comment: Yes again, and it is the `why` of my question: What is usage?

Comment: I deserialize JSON, which contains array of object of specified type

Answer (score 2):

You can use somewhat of a workaround with  the magic of `dynamic` keyword:

```
interface ICar {}
interface IAnimal {}

class Program
{
    static void Dispatch(dynamic list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispatch called");
        DoSomething(list);
    }

    static void DoSomething<T>(List<T> genericList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic unconstrained method called");
    }

    static void DoSomething(List<IAnimal> animalList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something WILD");
    }

    static void DoSomething(List<ICar> carList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculate loans");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        object deserializedList = new List<ICar>();
        Dispatch(deserializedList);
    }
}
```

Comment: static void DoSomething<T>(List<T> genericList)
will use List<object> :) No need for dynamic

Comment: @alerya but with DoSomething<T> you don't have type; you can't use the methods. This is a nice way of giving you all the type info. (sans reflection)

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to create a strong typed list. You won't have that type for use in code, but the list type will be fixed.

```
//DetermineSerializedType here would be your own method to determine the type you have
Type deserializedType = DetermineSerializedType(serializedData);

Type genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(deserializedType);
ConstructorInfo ctor = genericType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
object inst = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });
IList list = inst as IList;
```

**EDIT** Personally I think the dynamic solution Grozz gives is cleaner.

Comment: how is this any better than an `object[]` ?

Comment: And use the Activator to create an instance of the generic list type. I had to create a custome Serializer and this works.

Comment: @HighCore Because he didn't ask for an object[]